# Benefit of using Set Based Query over RBAR Query

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, database

At first, I am apologizing for my bad English.

The problem is--

In my Database, I have a table consisting of 307763 rows. Everyday I need to process each row.To Process the rows I write a SQL query to SELECT, INSERT and UPDATE in the database.Execution time for the query is  **30 minutes** to **1 hour**.

Then I made a Visual Studio console application to run the process.

Here is the problem arise. In App.Config there is a time limit for Database Connection Time Out for 30 seconds. I also tried to by making the value to 0.

Is there any secure way to keep the connection open for 1 hour or any other way to solve the problem?

Here is the query:

```
DECLARE @totalEmployee AS INT;
DECLARE @i AS INT=1;
DECLARE @employee TABLE
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    SystemId VARCHAR(30),
    PreRecruitmentEmployeeId VARCHAR(30),
    DOJ DATETIME,
    DOS DATETIME,
    ProbationConfirmEntryDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @employee
SELECT EI.SystemId, EI.PreRecruitmentEmployeeId, EI.DOJ, EI.DOS, EI.ProbationConfirmEntryDate FROM EmployeeInformation EI WHERE EI.EmployeeStatus='Active';
SELECT @totalEmployee=COUNT(*) FROM @employee;
WHILE @i<= @totalEmployee
  BEGIN
    UPDATE EmployeeDocument SET 
           DueProcessDateTime=CASE WHEN ED.DueProcessDateTime IS NULL THEN GETDATE() ELSE ED.DueProcessDateTime END, 
           IsMailSend=CASE WHEN ED.DueProcessDateTime IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE ED.IsMailSend END,
           DueDate=
            CASE 
                WHEN CD.DependateDate='AsAndWhen' THEN NULL
                WHEN CD.DependateDate='AppointmentDate' THEN 
                    CASE WHEN E.PreRecruitmentEmployeeId IS NULL AND E.DOJ IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays, E.DOJ) ELSE
                        CASE WHEN PRE.ApprovedDateTime IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays, PRE.ApprovedDateTime) 
                        END
                    END
                WHEN CD.DependateDate='AgreedJoinDate' THEN
                    CASE WHEN E.PreRecruitmentEmployeeId IS NULL AND E.DOJ IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays, E.DOJ) ELSE
                        CASE WHEN PRE.AgreedDOJ IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays, PRE.AgreedDOJ) 
                        END
                    END
                WHEN CD.DependateDate='ResignationApplyDate' THEN (SELECT TOP(1) CASE WHEN ResignationDate<>'' THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays,ResignationDate)
                                                                    ELSE NULL END FROM TRN.Resignation WHERE EmployeeId=E.SystemId  ORDER BY ResignationDate DESC)
                WHEN CD.DependateDate='ApprovedResignationEffectiveDate' THEN (SELECT TOP(1) CASE WHEN ApprovedEffectiveDate<>'' THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays,ApprovedEffectiveDate)
                                                                    ELSE NULL END FROM TRN.Resignation WHERE EmployeeId=E.SystemId  ORDER BY ApprovedEffectiveDate DESC)
                WHEN CD.DependateDate='JoiningDate' AND E.DOJ IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays, E.DOJ)
                WHEN CD.DependateDate='LetterOfIndentDate' THEN 
                    CASE WHEN E.PreRecruitmentEmployeeId IS NULL AND E.DOJ IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays, E.DOJ) ELSE
                        CASE WHEN PRE.SelectionDateTime IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays, PRE.SelectionDateTime) 
                        END
                    END
                WHEN CD.DependateDate='ProfileSubmit' THEN 
                    CASE WHEN E.PreRecruitmentEmployeeId IS NULL AND E.DOJ IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays, E.DOJ) ELSE
                        CASE WHEN PRE.SelectionDateTime IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays, PRE.SelectionDateTime) 
                        END
                    END
                WHEN CD.DependateDate='ProbitionPeriodConfirmationDate' AND E.ProbationConfirmEntryDate IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays, E.ProbationConfirmEntryDate)
                WHEN CD.DependateDate='PromotionDate' THEN NULL
                WHEN CD.DependateDate='SeparationDate' AND E.DOS IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays, E.DOS)
                WHEN CD.DependateDate='SelectionDate' THEN
                CASE WHEN E.PreRecruitmentEmployeeId IS NULL AND E.DOJ IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays, E.DOJ) ELSE
                        CASE WHEN PRE.SelectionDateTime IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays, PRE.SelectionDateTime) 
                        END
                    END
            END
        FROM EmployeeDocument ED
        JOIN HKP.ComplianceDocument CD ON CD.Id=ED.ComplianceDocumentId
        LEFT JOIN @employee E ON E.SystemId=ED.EmpSystemID
        LEFT JOIN PreRecruitmentEmployee PRE ON PRE.Id=E.PreRecruitmentEmployeeId
        WHERE E.Id=@i AND ED.FileId IS NULL                     
    SET @i = @i + 1;
  END
```

Comment: It would be better to help you if you share the related code

Comment: this execution time in total for each query or for a single one query? if for a single query you should consider to change/split your query

Comment: The connection time out does not indicate how much time the connection can stay open. It indicates how much time the connection can spend attempting to connect to the database.

Comment: you should ask question like "how do I minimize the execution time ?" rather than increasing connection time.i think you can increae connection time in web config and Sqlcommand timeout both.along with this you can use pool in conn string.

Comment: Thanks, @KumarHarsh for the advise I have changed the title.

Comment: @SamanGholami I add a google drive link of the code. 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EvHeAyMG2dKKqxS1V0pK9_sZgEUwume0nRD2gzB4G7A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: A good question is self contained. Not everyone might have access to content hiding behind links. You should include in your question a [mcve]. In SQL related questions that usually contains the relevant tables DDL, sample data as DML, and desired results. In SQL performance questions that also include the execution plan.

Comment: @Badiparmagi It is for a single query.

Comment: Dear @ZoharPeled I am extremely sorry for my haphazard presentation,And thanks for your kind suggestion.

Comment: Don't be sorry, just [edit] your question. as a rule of thumb, if you want good answers, you should ask good questions. If your question doesn't get answers, it's not my problem, it's yours...

Comment: I've edited your question for you to include the SQL Statement as formatted text. Please do that yourself next tme. Your problem is probably the fact that your SQL Statement uses a RBAR approach with that loop. It would run a lot faster if it was re-written with a set based approach.

Comment: Forget about extending timeouts.Write a set based query that will probably run in ten minutes, not an hour. (BTW its _command_ timeout, not _connection_ timeout that you need).

Comment: read my comment below Zohar answer. Also table variable is stick no-no for even few hundred record. Use temp table instead.

Comment: Thanks @KumarHarsh for your helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that we can see your sql statement, we can suggest a better approach.

Your current SQL statement is using a loop, meaning it **runs once for every single record** in the `@Employee` table variable. This procedural approach is known as RBAR - (RBAR is pronounced "ree-bar" and is a "Modenism" for "Row-By-Agonizing-Row" - coined by Jeff Moden - an SQL guru) - because it is, well, agonizingly slow. (Here is [one of many articles](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-road-to-professional-database-development-set-based-thinking/) on the subject for some more information)

SQL does not work well with this approach. Instead, it works well with a set based approach - meaning you let it work on a set of records instead of going one by one.

So here is how **I think** your sql statement should look like (Note I've traded the `@Employees` table variable with a simple derived table, so there's no need to worry about that).

**Please note** I have no way of testing this, since you didn't provide sample data nor desired results, so you need to test it yourself - but the principle stands - Never go RBAR when you can avoid it.

```
UPDATE EmployeeDocument 
SET DueProcessDateTime = CASE WHEN ED.DueProcessDateTime IS NULL THEN GETDATE() ELSE ED.DueProcessDateTime END, 
    IsMailSend = CASE WHEN ED.DueProcessDateTime IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE ED.IsMailSend END,
    DueDate = 
        CASE 
        WHEN CD.DependateDate='AsAndWhen' THEN NULL
        WHEN CD.DependateDate='AppointmentDate' THEN 
            CASE WHEN E.PreRecruitmentEmployeeId IS NULL AND E.DOJ IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays, E.DOJ) ELSE
                CASE WHEN PRE.ApprovedDateTime IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays, PRE.ApprovedDateTime) 
                END
            END
        WHEN CD.DependateDate='AgreedJoinDate' THEN
            CASE WHEN E.PreRecruitmentEmployeeId IS NULL AND E.DOJ IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays, E.DOJ) ELSE
                CASE WHEN PRE.AgreedDOJ IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays, PRE.AgreedDOJ) 
                END
            END
        WHEN CD.DependateDate='ResignationApplyDate' THEN (SELECT TOP(1) CASE WHEN ResignationDate<>'' THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays,ResignationDate)
                                                            ELSE NULL END FROM TRN.Resignation WHERE EmployeeId=E.SystemId  ORDER BY ResignationDate DESC)
        WHEN CD.DependateDate='ApprovedResignationEffectiveDate' THEN (SELECT TOP(1) CASE WHEN ApprovedEffectiveDate<>'' THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays,ApprovedEffectiveDate)
                                                            ELSE NULL END FROM TRN.Resignation WHERE EmployeeId=E.SystemId  ORDER BY ApprovedEffectiveDate DESC)
        WHEN CD.DependateDate='JoiningDate' AND E.DOJ IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays, E.DOJ)
        WHEN CD.DependateDate='LetterOfIndentDate' THEN 
            CASE WHEN E.PreRecruitmentEmployeeId IS NULL AND E.DOJ IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays, E.DOJ) ELSE
                CASE WHEN PRE.SelectionDateTime IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays, PRE.SelectionDateTime) 
                END
            END
        WHEN CD.DependateDate='ProfileSubmit' THEN 
            CASE WHEN E.PreRecruitmentEmployeeId IS NULL AND E.DOJ IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays, E.DOJ) ELSE
                CASE WHEN PRE.SelectionDateTime IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays, PRE.SelectionDateTime) 
                END
            END
        WHEN CD.DependateDate='ProbitionPeriodConfirmationDate' AND E.ProbationConfirmEntryDate IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays, E.ProbationConfirmEntryDate)
        WHEN CD.DependateDate='PromotionDate' THEN NULL
        WHEN CD.DependateDate='SeparationDate' AND E.DOS IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays, E.DOS)
        WHEN CD.DependateDate='SelectionDate' THEN
            CASE WHEN E.PreRecruitmentEmployeeId IS NULL AND E.DOJ IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays, E.DOJ) ELSE
                CASE WHEN PRE.SelectionDateTime IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, CD.LeadOrLagDays, PRE.SelectionDateTime) 
                END
            END
        END
FROM EmployeeDocument ED
JOIN HKP.ComplianceDocument CD ON CD.Id=ED.ComplianceDocumentId
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT EI.SystemId, EI.PreRecruitmentEmployeeId, EI.DOJ, EI.DOS, EI.ProbationConfirmEntryDate 
    FROM EmployeeInformation EI 
    WHERE EI.EmployeeStatus='Active'
) E ON E.SystemId=ED.EmpSystemID
LEFT JOIN PreRecruitmentEmployee PRE ON PRE.Id=E.PreRecruitmentEmployeeId
WHERE ED.FileId IS NULL
```

Comment: @Abdullah-Al-Mamun ,Zohar answer is towards correct direction.Even if output is not correct then it can be corrected in same approach.no doubts your query need further improvement

Comment: @KumarHarsh Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help :-) btw, your English seems fine to me (though I'm a non-native English speaker myself :-))